# How to merge or split overlapping dates?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am currently stuck on a problem and trying to find a viable solution for it. For context, I am working with EXTJS, and in our system, we have a tab panel and inside the each tab is a grid with data. We can drop things and we dynamically create tabs and populate grid. The things we dropped have duration, a list of dates and we modify the tabs to reflect those dates. Example is I dropped something that has date (1/9), a tab is created with title 1/9 and data is loaded into grid for that date. Whenever an item is dropped, the server will correctly returns a list of dates, and base on this I create the tab and modify title with the dates. The dates can either be single or a list of its own as well. Here are the 2 types of data return. Type 1: `[1/8,1/9]` and type 2 `[ [1/8 ], [1/9] ]` or a combination of both. `[1/5, [1/6, 1/7], 1/8]`.

What I am doing is looping the list and if the current item is an array, I am concatenating the dates (1/6 - 1/7) a tab was created for each item in list (3 in above case). The dates can be disjointed or consecutive.

The issue is before dropping something, there could be existing tabs with their own dates, maybe same dates we get back from server. What I want is either merge or separate overlapping dates base on a condition. I want to ignore dates I get back from server that is not overlapping. for example, if there are is a tab with dates `(1/5, 1/6)` and I get back `(1/7`) from server, we simply ignore, no tabs are created.

Example:

**Given a tab with dates:**

**[1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9]**

After dropping item, I get get back **[ [1/8], [1/9] ]**  from server

I want to modify the first tab and change it 1/5 - 1/8 and then create a second tab and give 1/9 as date.

Reason is because if I were to drop item and get back **[ [1/8], [1/9] ]**  from server without any prior tabs, we will have 2 tabs since it is a list within a list.

**Given a tab with dates:**

**[1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9]**

After dropping item, I get get back **[1/8, 1/9]**  from server

I want to have 1 tab with dates **1/5 - 1/9**

Reason: because the dates are single and not list within a list and they both overlap tab dates, we don't add or modify the tab

Dates don't overlap example

**Given a tab with date:**

**[1/9]**

After dropping item, I get get back **[1/8, 1/9]** or `[ [1/8], [1/9] ]` from server (depends on item drop)

I want to have 1 tab with date 1/9 because the tab doesn't have 1/8 so that date is ignored.

There could be multiple tabs with single/ multiple dates that overlap or don't overlap dates return by server.

My approach:

1. I was iterating existing tabs and getting dates of each tab.
2. I am comparing against server dates to see if any overlap occur
3. I ignore the tab if it doesn't have any dates or the tab dates doesn't overlap the server dates

I don't have actual code because I was stuck on the logic part but here is a pseudocode of something I tried (javascript language)

Exp: 1 tab exists with dates **[1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9]** and I dropped item and server returns **[ [1/8, 1/9] ]**

```
const itemDates = content; (from server)

tabs.forEach(function(tab, index){

let tabDates = tab.getDates();

// skip if tab has no dates
if(tabDates.length > 0) {

// use tab index to retrieve date from itemDates
const currentItemDate = itemDates[index];

// it could be null since index can be out of bounds
if(currentItemDate){

 
//we will ignore if currentItemDate is a list because it either has to be already present in the tab 
//or it will be dates that are not overlapping
 
// if single date, we want to create new tab as neccessary
if(!Array.isArray(currentItemDate){

// there is at least one date overlap
if(tabDates.some(date => currentItemDate.includes(date)) {

}

// 

}
 
 }

 }


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is too long, but I think that's what you're trying to do, from what I've skimmed.

```
function updateTabs(existingTabs, serverDates) {
    serverDates.forEach(serverDate => {
        // Check if serverDate is an array (list of dates) or a single date
        if (Array.isArray(serverDate)) {
            // Handle the case where serverDate is a list of dates
            serverDate.forEach(date => {
                updateTabs(existingTabs, [date]); // Recursively handle each date in the list
            });
        } else {
            // Handle the case where serverDate is a single date
            let overlappingTabs = existingTabs.filter(tab => tabHasOverlap(tab, serverDate));

            if (overlappingTabs.length > 0) {
                // Overlapping tabs exist, update them
                overlappingTabs.forEach(tab => updateTab(tab, serverDate));
            }
        }
    });
}

function tabHasOverlap(tab, date) {
    // Check if the given date overlaps with any date in the tab
    return tab.getDates().some(tabDate => date.includes(tabDate) || tabDate.includes(date));
}

function updateTab(tab, date) {
    // Update the existing tab with the given date
    // You may implement the logic to update a tab here
    console.log("Update tab with date:", date);
}

// Example usage:
const existingTabs = [
    { getDates: () => ["1/9"] },
    // Add other existing tabs as needed
];

const serverDates = [["1/8", "1/9"]];
updateTabs(existingTabs, serverDates);
```

Comment: Hi refik, thanks for adding a  solution. I have tried your solution with this data sample  below and it is adding a new tab which is not expected. Since 1/8 is not part of existingTabs, we will ignore it. 

tab Dates ["1/9"]


 server Dates: [["1/8", "1/9"]]


Expected will be: 1 tab with date 1/9

Comment: then I think you want that a new tab is only created if the server dates completely overlap with an existing tab. I edited it, but I'm not so sure. It's more complicated than it seems.

Comment: I want to create a new tab if the server has a list of dates [["1/8", "1/9"]] and they both overlap the tab, then we create a  new tab for 1/9. if for example tab date was ["1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9, 1/10"] and server dates was  [["1/8"], ["1/9"], ["1/10"] ], there will be 3 tabs. First tab is 1/5 - 1/8, a second is 1/9 and third tab is 1/10. if 1/10 was not overlapping with tab date, it will just be 2 tabs  1/5 - 1/8 and 1/9. it is complicated. I think we can just filter out all dates in list other than first date from tab, then we either create new tab if overlap with tab dates or ignore